# Creating Objects in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am Facing a problem while working with Kubernetes and I can't be able to find solutions for that.

```
$ kubectl create -f ./my-manifest.yaml           # create resource(s)
$ kubectl create -f ./my1.yaml -f ./my2.yaml     # create from multiple files
```

and getting an error:

```
error: the path "./my-manifest.yaml" does not exist
```

please help me to resolve this problem

Comment: That seems like a pretty clear error message; can you say more about your setup, and have you verified that the files you're using do actually exist?

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear: Either the files don't exist in the directory or there is some kind of spelling error in the file name.

Let's break this down:

1. You can use the **ls** command to list the files in the current directory and verify the file's presence.
2. Make sure the file "./my-manifest.yaml" exists in the current directory. Verify the file name and ensure it is spelled correctly.
3. If the file is located in a different directory, provide the complete path to the file instead of using a relative path. For example: **kubectl create -f /path/to/my-manifest.yaml**